# Can iptables fail open after a configuration error?

Tags: iptables

Even the greatest of minds make mistakes;

If I make a mistake on a remote server in my stored iptables rules that are loaded at start up, then next time the machine restarts I'm locked out.

So, say in a sleepy state I put an extra dot in an IP address, this error causes iptables to just freak out and drop all traffic, rules prior to this one are ignore, it just does nothing which is useless to me.

Can I make it just fail open or something if there is an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when making changes to your iptables configuration always put something in cron that will restore them to a sane state every 10 minutes (or whatever).

Comment: I do think about this, but everytime I make a change on any server I would have to first make a copy of the current rules, then add a cron job, make the change, then remove the cron job again. Bit much when making simple rule changes. Does iptables really not have any sort of option to not shit the bed, in the rather stupid fasion that is does, in the event of simple human error?

Comment: I don't think it has that option. I have a script that just sets a simple sane configuration every 10 minutes that would allow me back in. Takes 10 seconds to uncomment and I know I'm safe.

Comment: @javano "Don't make errors".  Software does not exist to protect us from ourselves, it exists to do what we tell it to.  If you expect to make an error (you're human, you should expect this) it's up to you to create an appropriate backout plan, such as the cron job Iain suggested...

Answer (score 2):

`iptables` follows whatever instructions you give it.  A incorrectly formatted argument won't cause iptables to dump all it's rules... (i.e. an extra `.` someplace...) but an incorrect rule that *is* valid... will certainly be problematic... including dump all traffic... or accept everything.

i.e. valid statements that are probably bad include:

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -I INPUT -j DROP
```

or even

```
iptables -F
```

but a rule like

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168..11 -j ACCEPT
```

should spit out an error.  The only time one or more rules get "deleted" or "removed" are when you flush a table (`-F`), delete a rule (`-D`) or delete a chain (`-X`).  As long as you're not messing with those 3 options... you can always delete the bad rule & move on.

Comment: This is OK if you are typing commands in one at a time. I'm talking about at system start up, the iptables rules are restored from a saved config, it has many lines in it, if one of them is wrong, the whole thing falls over.

Comment: Saving/restoring iptables rules is not something iptables does by itself.  Depending on the distribution you're using... they may have built in scripts that will save on start/shutdown... but imho... that isn't a very good idea.  Still... even if one line is bad... it still should not have problems ignoring that one line & moving on.